# NuGet package without assemblies complains about lack of assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I'm creating a content-only NuGet package (e.g. no DLLs, just text files in this case). When I install the package, I get this error message:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'CodeGenerator.Templates.EF6-CQRS-Aurelia 1.0.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or 
>   content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

This is all true, but I don't want to target any framework for this package -- how can I accomplish this?

The package is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CodeGenerator.Templates.EF6-CQRS-Aurelia

Comment: How are you generating the package? Can you post the command and/or the nuspec file?

Comment: BTW I opened the package using Nuget Package Explorer and I just noticed that there is a `lib` folder that contains all the templates. I have the impression that `lib` is a reserved name, try to rename that folder to something else such as `templates`

Comment: I'm using NuGet Package Explorer to edit/build the package. Will try your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to having a nuget package with no content files?

Comment: @glpj For now I just ended up adding a framework dependency to get past this. I haven't had a chance to dig in to this more since I asked this question, but once I do, I'll post here if I have anything to share!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem but with only a *build* target (and no assemblies).

Just adding an empty `lib` folder to my root package directory fixed it.

(Maybe a bug in NuGet. I have submitted an [issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3668).)